# Sort a file according to one column content

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a file with two columns. I would like to sort the file according to the content of the first column. The first column contains elements that look like:

```
unc.edu.08d85849-cda7-4709-a934-fdc586418d7f.1150908.rsem
unc.edu.05aa0960-505b-4b04-be9f-7b54940f5b27.1153406.rsem
unc.edu.2b11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
```

I would like to sort according to the first numerical element, that is "08d85849". I tried with the following string but without success:

```
sort -o output.txt -t '-' -k 2n myfile.txt
```

Desired output:

> ```
> unc.edu.2b11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem     
> unc.edu.05aa0960-505b-4b04-be9f-7b54940f5b27.1153406.rsem     
> unc.edu.08d85849-cda7-4709-a934-fdc586418d7f.1150908.rsem
> ```

Comment: one value is not the best way to show what the input looks like. Is it always after the 2nd dot? Try to provide a more broad input and desired output.

Comment: In what way is `2b`, `05`, `08` sorted?  You seem to have a strange ordering in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), third column (HEX value) sorted and delimited by `.` :

**INPUT**

```
unc.edu.08d85849-cda7-4709-a934-fdc586418d7f.1150908.rsem
unc.edu.05aa0960-505b-4b04-be9f-7b54940f5b27.1153406.rsem
unc.edu.2b11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
unc.edu.ff11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
unc.edu.aa11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
```

**CODE**

using [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

```
$ perl -F'\.' -anle '
    push @hexs, [$F[2],$_];
    END {
        print for map  { $_->[0] }
                  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                  map  { [$_->[1],hex($_->[0])] } @hexs;
    }
' file
```

**OUTPUT**

```
unc.edu.05aa0960-505b-4b04-be9f-7b54940f5b27.1153406.rsem
unc.edu.08d85849-cda7-4709-a934-fdc586418d7f.1150908.rsem
unc.edu.2b11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
unc.edu.aa11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
unc.edu.ff11e565-01a8-4054-a200-03e06765bd5e.1174035.rsem
```

Adapted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139801/sort-by-hex-value

Comment: you added a lot of content, which is nice, but we still don't know what pattern is the OP using to sort.